# Run fsck in the background on boot

Tags: boot, fstab, fsck

Running openSUSE 15.1 with systemd, when it determined the need, the boot processes will invoke `fsck` on a particular disk. By default, this check will run in the foreground, blocking the completion of the boot processes. This has led [some to desire to stop the boot-time checking completely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/239709/13308).

I understand if my OS partition may have undergone some data corruption, `fsck` should block before continuing to process data on the disk. However, some of my disks are less essential to the operation of the system. Can I indicate to the system to run the `fsck` in the background and mount the disk on success, but to let the system load normally otherwise, either via a flag in `fstab` or another method?

Comment: Do you want fsck to run before boot completion selectively, only on specific disks (i.e., boot drive), and post-boot on other drives? Please click [edit] and confirm; a list of each drive and your check boot/check later preference might be helpful to use with the -t option. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, please use [edit]. Editing tips are at https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code .

Comment: fsck needs to run on a file-system that is either unmounted or mounted read-only.  your system can't boot normally unless it can mount its usual filesystem(s) read-write.    Depending on what fs you're using, you should be able to tune the parameters that trigger an automatic fsck on boot (e.g. mount count and interval between checks on ext2/3/4 using `tune2fs`).    Alternatively, you could use a filesystem like `btrfs` or `zfs` that don't need fsck, but can run `scrub` operation while the filesystem is online and in active, normal use.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43698/importance-of-fsck-at-boot-with-journalled-filesystems

Comment: Yes; as the question mentioned, I don't have a problem with running `fsck`, and even the block of the loading of the system for essential disks. I am asking for a way to run `fsck` at boot, but not block the loading of the system for disks I have specified as non-essential.

Comment: FreeBSD has had this functionality since late 2001, but to my knowledge, [the requisite changes that underlie background fsck](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/bsdcon/mckusick/mckusick_html/) have never been adopted by Linux.  If you find a solution outside of SE, please come back and answer your own post.  It's an interesting puzzle.